# Node ~ Falha na segmentação

Tags: node.js

Eu atualizei meu NodeJS para a versão LTS atual e agora ele só retorna um erro de Falha na segmentação

[image: Imagem do erro no nodejs]

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente, **qualquer erro** com `npm` distribuído via repositórios sempre confirme se não é falta de atualizar o programa, seu problema pode ser com o node, pode ser com o npm pode ser com o Ubuntu, veja se esta tudo atualizado com correções (não falo de updgrade, só update mesmo), para resumir o comando é:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

No terminal, verifique a versão do node e npm usadas com os comandos:

```
node -v
npm -v
```

Creio que a esta altura (28/05/2019), mesmo em ambientes linux a versão do Node.js tem que ser a 10.x, do NPM tem que ser 6.9.x (não sei em que situação anda, talvez edite a resposta)

### A interface de linha de comando `expo-cli` deve ser instalada globalmente (*flag* `-g`)

Agora sobre o `expo-cli`, ele é um pacote para aplicar uma interface de linha de comando, eu realmente creio que você nem precise rodar isso com `sudo`, já que a intenção é usar no usuário atual e não em `root` (posso estar enganado), bastaria rodar isto:

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

Pronto, já teria instalado para o **seu usuário** atual o `expo`, para verificar se ele funcionou digite no terminal:

```
expo --help
```

Nem é preciso editar o arquivo `~/.profile` para tornar o comando "global", porque ele roda sob o `npm` (creio eu, me corrijam se eu estiver equivocado)

Comment: Boa resposta. +1 :) No entanto, acho errado afirmar que "interfaces de linha de comando devem ser instaladas globalmente", uma vez que esse nem sempre é o caso.

Comment: Caro @LuizFelipe e como pretende rodar um CLI dinâmico (tipo expo-cli, express-cli, http-server cli, ionic/cli, **gulp**) que não rode "globalmente"? Tem algum exemplo de CLI que consiga ser limitado a pasta do projeto? Que talvez crie um `.bat` (ou um bash) na pasta sozinho? Realmente nunca ouvi falar de algo assim, mas ficaria grato com sua critica e apontamento ;)

Comment: Em um `npm script`, por exemplo. Quando você instala um _package_ que disponibiliza um "binário", ele é resolvido quando executado pelo script NPM. Nesse sentido, algo que faço muito é instalar a CLI do ESLint localmente por projeto, fazendo uso de um script `lint` definido como `eslint .` para lintar os meus arquivos. Assim, não preciso instalar globalmente e deixo isso por projeto. [Um exemplo aqui](https://github.com/lffg/code-in-js/blob/master/package.json#L9).

Comment: Entendo sua colocação Luiz, mas ai a interface é o proprio NPM, o comando em si não é global, esses são comandos do `devDependencies` geralmente e não de fato "interfaces", mas é como vejo, vou mudar o texto para ficar mais claro nisto depois, ainda não pensei bem em como escrever :)

Comment: Sim! Mas continuam sendo CLI's, só que ao invés de serem instaladas globalmente, são instaladas pelo projeto. Nada impede de instalar também como `dependencies`...

Comment: @LuizFelipe acho que isso é ir demais ao fundo e misturar com "semântica" para explicar as coisas tecnicamente XD ... melhor deixar ver outra forma de explicar, pq realmente creio que ai é o npm que faz uma chamada de algo dentro, mas fique tranquilo que hoje mesmo edito ;)

Comment: Sim. :v Por baixo dos panos é o NPM que chama o comando mesmo...

Comment: @LuizFelipe editei a resposta de forma a afirmar somente sobre o uso exclusivo do `expo-cli`... ps: sim, quase tudo por baixo é NPM, assim como em composer, tudo por baixo é php+bat+phar, o que não impede do entendimento no final ser **como funciona** e não o que foi usado para se desenvolver tal ferramenta, mas como já disse, é uma opinião minha :)